# Primefaces 8.0 Calendar popup within Dialog is positioned relative to parent screen scroll position

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have recreated a minimal reproducible example for the following question [p:calendar popup remain below from calendar input in dialog when scroll (on IE and Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078047/pcalendar-popup-remain-below-from-calendar-input-in-dialog-when-scroll-on-ie-a).  I have also been encountering this issue and just figured out what was happening but I do not know how to fix it. The `appendTo` suggestion in the referenced question for `selectOneMenu` does not seem to be an attribute we can apply to the calendar.

Here is how to reproduce:

- If the parent window is scrolled to the top, the calendar popup on the dialog is positioned correctly
- If the parent window is scrolled down a little, the calendar popup on the dialog is positioned a little further down from the input box
- The distance offset is seems relative to the amount the parent window is scrolled.
- the `top` value seems to be the culprit.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui" xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">

<h:head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h1>Calendar Popup Issue PF 8.0</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h:panelGrid id="gridId">
        <h:panelGrid id="panelId">
            <h:form id="laborForm">
                <p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('dialogWv').show()" title="Click to open dialog" update="dialogId" value="Open dialog with popup time only calendar" />
            </h:form>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />



    <p:dialog id="dialogId" header="Test" dynamic="true" widgetVar="dialogWv" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
        resizable="true" width="400px" height="100px">
        <h:form id="formId">
            <p:panelGrid style="margin-bottom: 5px; border: 2px; width: 100%;" id="pg1">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="2">
                        <p:calendar  value="#{cc.attrs.viewBean.backfitTime}" timeOnly="true" pattern="HH:mm" showMillisec="false" showSecond="false" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Time is required" rendered="true" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <br />
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>




</h:body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
I am unable upgrade to PF10 at the moment due to too much of my site's look and feel getting broke with 10.  So my short term fix was just to use the datePicker but with PF8.  But the datePicker with PF8 doesn't render nice.  Plus the mouse pointer covers the hour and minute numbers when incrementing up.

[image]

Clicking an up or down arrow is inefficient.

Comment: this is fixed in PF 10.0.0.RC1 or higher.  I fixed this. See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6583

Comment: By the way, please don't chameleonize your question into a new question. If you have a new question, please post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in PrimeFaces 10.0.0RC1 or higher.

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6583

Comment: OK.  I actually did try 10 when it first came out but reverted back to 8 because it really changed the look of my site.  I wasn't ready to adjust my theme at the time. But I also now want to pick up your fix to the other bug I had found https://stackoverflow.com/a/64821946/358794 so I guess I will upgrade back to 10.

Comment: Yeah the themes are changing in 10 so if you use a premium theme you may have to wait to get the new 10 version from PrimeTek.

Comment: No custom theme, I never specified one in Web.xml, but made tweaks using style or styleClass or i.e. used icon="ui-icon-circle-arrow-e" on my commandButton.  I think the icons I used are probably deprecated as they are not showing.  Also disabled buttons in 10 don't look disabled.  datatable groupBy looks to have changed as I am now getting serlvet error. This is why I reverted back to 8.  I should probably post another question about v10 rather than cram it into this comment.  Not complaining or ungrateful, PF is awesome, just need bite the bullet and update my site.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`p:datePicker`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/datepicker/datePickerJava8.xhtml) instead of `p:calendar`. `DatePicker` is designed to replace the old `p:calendar` component. The `p:datePicker` (at least the one in PrimeFaces 10) uses `absolute` positioning instead of `fixed`, so that should solve your problem.

See also:

- [Can I position an element fixed relative to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209814/can-i-position-an-element-fixed-relative-to-parent)
- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/datepicker

Comment: I didn't realize v8 actually had a datePicker component.

Comment: I believe it's there since 7, although it was buggy in that release. I'm using it in 8 without major issues.

Comment: Did you restyle the datePicker in v8?  Due to v10 breaking a lot of things with my site, for now I'd like to just switch to datePicker in v8 and then work on moving to 10.  But the style of the popup does not look good in my site using v8.  See my edited post for screenshot.

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/timePicker.jsf

Comment: Thanks, I had already check it out.  Not desirable to show 24 and 60 individual hour and minute buttons.